# Самая эффективная замена memcpy

Tags: c

Нужно копировать большую область памяти, не используя string.h. Какой код, заменяющий memcpy, работает предельно эффективно по скорости? Первое, что приходит на ум, - это

```
char *destination, *source;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    destination[i] = source[i];
```

Если это не самый быстрый вариант, то как ускорить его на C без ассемблера?

Comment: Какая архитектура, какой компилятор? Возможно достаточно выставить соответствующие ключики оптимизации.

Comment: Процессор - x86, компилятор - gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не самый эффективный метод, но и не самый плохой. Очевидно, что можно копировать быстрее, если учитывать специфику железа памяти, а именно, тот факт, что память читается блоками, а не байтами или резмерами регистра.

Можно также почитать разные мелкие манипуляции по оптимизации самого цикла и индексации:
http://www.danielvik.com/2010/02/fast-memcpy-in-c.html.

Comment: Рекоммендую книгу http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1418882/ . Я читал её когда-то давно и в ней как раз разбирались многие вопросы, связанные с работой памяти, как физического устройства, и как раз там был разбор полётов и про memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

думаю что написать быстрее чем memcpy врят ли удастся - она может быть довольно сильно оптимизированна - библиотека хоть и сишная, но есть практически на любой платформе и реализовать ее могут разработчики платформы. но если уж совсем охота то вот идея - реализация - писть не буду долго. Надо копировать не по байтам отдельным а по 4 или 8 байтов (в зависимости от того 32 битная или 64 битная ли система). просто часто при копировании 1 байта регистр получается задействован не полностью. если совсем писать быструю - то можно написать системно зависимую функу - попробовать поискать функции работы с памятью минуя ядро - в этом вопросе не спец, могу и наврать.

Comment: >> попробовать поискать функции работы с памятью минуя ядро
Как насчёт операции присвоения? Она вполне подходит, будучи выполненной не через ядро

Comment: По поводу регистров - верно, но это самое минимальное, что можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

> не используя string.h.

А что можно? memcpy объявлен в memory.h, а не в string.h. Если хотите быстро, возьмите дизассемблерный код от memcpy.